# Discord bot stops working after one response

Tags: javascript, bots, discord

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');

const client = new Discord.Client();

const Prefix = '!';

client.once('ready', () => {
    console.log('Bot is online!');
});

client.once('message', message=>{

    let args = message.content.substring(Prefix.length).split(" ");

    switch(args[0]){
        case 'ping':
            message.channel.send('pong');
        break;
    };
})


client.login('[Token]');
```

When i say !ping to my bot it says pong like i wanted but when i say it again it wont respond with ping

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would say, that you need to have your code like `client.on` not `client.once`. Also you can check [discord.js](https://discord.js.org/#/) they have an easy example there about this.

Also talking about other parts of you code I would suggest to use `.split(' ')` `.split(" ")` but I think there would be no difference in this situation.

And maybe it would be useful to convert all the message to **lowercase** because if somebody will sand `PING` this command will not work.

```
let command = args.shift().toLowerCase();
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the answer above `client.on()`, I believe you also want this:

1. You want to split with prefix `message.content.split(Prefix)`.
2. And then use `args[1]`.

(Note that there are other ways to do this as well. I made least modifications to your code.)

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');

const client = new Discord.Client();

const Prefix = '!';

client.on('ready', () => {
    console.log('Bot is online!');
});

client.on('message', message=>{

    let args = message.content.split(Prefix);

    switch(args[1]){
        case 'ping':
            message.channel.send('pong');
        break;
    };
})


client.login('[Token]');
```